# Javascript filter array by multiple strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, for-loop, keyword

I'm trying to filter an Array named *products* which is filled with one string per product.

```
var products = [
    'canadian black angus beef fresh',
    'canadian black angus beef frozen',
    'american black angus beef frozen'
];
```

The search starts by splitting an form input element by spaces in an array named *keywords* which contains an variable length of strings.

```
var keywords = ['angus', 'fresh'];
```

Actually I'm for-looping the product_array and make an 2nd (inner) for-loop for the keyword_array. Till now its all fine.

here is my shorten code which shows the issue:

```
function test() {
    
    var products = [
        'canadian black angus beef fresh',
        'canadian black angus beef frozen',
        'american black angus beef frozen'
    ];
    
    var keywords = ['angus', 'fresh'];
    var hits = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        
        for (var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {
            
            if (products[i].indexOf(keywords[j]) != -1) {
                
                /*
                a if case for looped '&&' operator 
                would be great - or something like that
                looped because of the variable length of keywords
                */
                hits.push(products[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    console.log(hits);
    /* 
    all products :/ - because all product matches with 'angus'
    but I'm searching for an product that contains 'angus' && 'fresh'
    */
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's unclear what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a flag that check if you have all keywords :

```
var containsAll;

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

    // Initialize flag -> guess that this product is correct
    containsAll = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {
        if (products[i].indexOf(keywords[j]) === -1) {
            // This keyword is not matched -> incorrect product
            containsAll = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // All products has been matched
    if (containsAll) hits.push(products[i]);
}
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eoz1y8n4/

Comment: "+1" oh yes. this is a better option. !

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should take a look at the `.filter()` function. It iterates through an array, and returns the items you want, based on a true/false return of the conditions you set.

[**MDN's Docs on Array.prototype.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Now, to be sure that both keywords exists, you can use some flag to indicate whether it does or doesn't:

```
var hits = products.filter(function(item) {
    var valid = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        if (item.indexOf(keywords[i]) === -1) {
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    return valid;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @LcSalazar, that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to make sure that your product has all of the keywords in it:

```js
function test() {

    var products = [
        'canadian black angus beef fresh',
        'canadian black angus beef frozen',
        'american black angus beef frozen'];

    var keywords = ['angus', 'fresh'];
    var hits = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        var allKeywordsMatch = true;
        for (var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {

            if (products[i].indexOf(keywords[j]) === -1) {

                allKeywordsMatch = false;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (allKeywordsMatch) hits.push(products[i]);

    }

    alert(hits);
}


test();
```

Comment: Hi @Mandera, your solution is working fine for me. thanks for sharing this. If posible can you please provide the same functionality using Array.map or Array.filter methods.

Comment: That's great to hear but I'm afraid I don't know how those methods work, hopefully someone else can help you

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped me lot to achieve desired result in searching and on the basis of this I have extended above given solution to search in Array of objects and in multiple fields like in Title, Category or Tags.

> I am posting my answer with code, just to become helpful if any developer need this in such case. Still there are chances for further improvements and I hope this will be helpful to someone.

My requirement was :

- To find search words either in Title (String), Category (String) or Array of Tags(Array of String).
- Search words can be multiple with space separated Ex. **"Es6 IIFE"**
- Search words can be anywhere in the string in any order

I have prepared one **live demo** for the same.You can run and check the result.

I have following sample Array of Objects with contains a **list of Articles**.

```
let articles = [
            { "title": "ES6 — set, map, weak", "category": "ES6", "tags": ["ES6", "Set", "Map", "Weak"] },
            { "title": "JavaScript Modules: From IIFEs to CommonJS to ES6 Modules", "category": "JavaScript", "tags": ["JavaScript", "Modules", "IIFE", "ES6 Modules"] },
            { "title": "A guide to JavaScript Regular Expressions", "category": "JavaScript", "tags": ["JavaScript", "RegExp", "Regular Expressions"] },
        ];
```

If any person types "es6 iife" in Search box and press the button then it will first look into Tags array, if not found there then it will look into Title and Category.

```js
let output = document.querySelector('#output');
let articles = [
 { "title": "ES6 — set, map, weak", "category": "ES6", "tags": ["ES6", "Set", "Map", "Weak"] },
 { "title": "JavaScript Modules: From IIFEs to CommonJS to ES6 Modules", "category": "JavaScript", "tags": ["JavaScript", "Modules", "IIFE", "ES6 Modules"] },
 { "title": "A guide to JavaScript Regular Expressions", "category": "JavaScript", "tags": ["JavaScript", "RegExp", "Regular Expressions"] },
];

let initialContent = '';
articles.map(article => {
 initialContent += `<li>
  <p><b>Title : </b> ${article.title}</p>
  <p><b>Category : </b> ${article.category}</p>
  <p><b>Tags : </b> ${article.tags}</p>
  </li>`;
});

output.innerHTML = initialContent;

function filter() {
 let searchTerm = document.querySelector('#searchBox').value;
 let keywords = searchTerm.split(' ');
 let articleBySearch = [];

 articles.map((article) => {
  let allKeywordsMatch = true;

  keywords.map((keyword) => {
   if (article.tags.some((tag) => tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) !== -1)) {
    allKeywordsMatch = true;
   } else {
    if (article.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) === -1 && article.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
     allKeywordsMatch = false;
    }
   }
  });

  if (allKeywordsMatch) articleBySearch.push(article);
 });

 // Display Output in the browser
 let htmlContent = '';
 articleBySearch.map(article => {
  htmlContent += `<li>
  <p><b>Title : </b> ${article.title}</p>
  <p><b>Category : </b> ${article.category}</p>
  <p><b>Tags : </b> ${article.tags}</p>
  </li>`;
 });

 output.innerHTML = htmlContent;
}
```

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.example {
 border: 1px solid rgb(245, 28, 118);
 width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 1em;
}

.example #searchBox {
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.example #searchBox:focus {
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #0059ff;
}

.example button {
 padding: 10px;
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #0059ff;
 border: 1px solid #0059ff;
}

.example ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.example li {
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 1em;
 margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="Type your words to search" />
  <button onClick="filter()">Click to Filter</button>
  <ul id="output"></ul>
</div>
```